# How do you change text of span and show a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create my own alert window that:
1.shows when I click a span that calls the function().
2. closes when I click the 'got it' button.
3. changes the text of span with the text provided.

But it's not working. It looks fine, but not working. Why?

I tried making it ID instead of CLASS, making it A...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<style> .tooltip:hover {color: green; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold;}</style>

<!-- the text I click to change the messagebox text-->
<span class="tooltip" onclick="alert_info('INFO')">Static</span>


<!-- the messagebox-->
<div class="popup_info" style=" top: 35%; left: 35%; border-radius: 10px;  border:3px groove #d1ded6; height: 150px;
 width: 400px; position: fixed; background-color: #c5d1c5;    font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; display: none;">
 <br>
 <center><span class="light_it">Information about the clicked button;</span></center><br><br><br><br> 

 <center><button class="close-info"   onclick="this.style.display = none;">Got it</button></center>
</div>
<!--the script that changes the text of the messagebox and shows it to me-->
<script>
function alert_info(text){
//change the span's text:
document.getElementByClassName('light_it').innerHTML = text;
//display the window containing the span of text:
document.getElementByClassName('popup_info').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want it to work properly: change the text of the window, show the window and close it when I click the button to close (display:none';).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see why by inspecting the console

[image]

You can fix that by replacing

`document.getElementByClassName('light_it').innerHTML = text;` by `document.getElementsByClassName('light_it')[0].innerHTML = text;`

and
`document.getElementByClassName('popup_info').style.display = "block";`
by
`document.getElementsByClassName('popup_info')[0].style.display = "block";`

Note that you also have an issue on the "close-info" button: `onclick="this.style.display = 'none';"`, missing quotes around `none`

Comment: thank you. Didnt knwo it has to be written as an array